# saving the highest sequence number of a collection in a variable

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am an Angular/Firestore beginner and try to solve the following problem:

I have a collection called "todosonserver" with several documents. Each of the documents includes a seqNr field. Whenever I add a new Todo to the collection, I would like to identify the highest seqNr of all documents in the collection and add 1.

My idea is a query that orders the documents by seqNr:

```
this.lastTodoSeqNr = this.db.collection<any>('todosonserver', ref => ref.orderBy('seqNr', 'desc').limit(1))
```

But I have no clue on how to proceed. I am sure some of you have a good solution for my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is good. Querying the collection based on the `seqNr`, order the results descending, and then limit the results to one, is the solution you can go ahead with. Is the best solution since it reaquires only one read. Alternatively, you can track that number by updating a document with the `seqNr` of the last document. That requires also a single read but it also requires an additional write operation when you add a new document.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Could you help me with some code to learn, how I can proceed? In the end I need a variable with the highest seqNr of all documents in it... would be great if you could provide some assistance...

Comment: THank you! But I still have some issues. Sorry - I am a beginner and just struggeling with at this point. I answered my piost with the error messages

Comment: I just rolled back my answer, so it cannot confuse future visitors. To solve this, you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Thank you! I am also new to stakoverflow so thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! If I try this, I recive the following 2 errors:

> Cannot find name 'flatMap'.
> and
> Parameter 'todosonserver' implicitly has an 'any' type.

As I am really stuck here, it would be great if you could provide me with a solution and some explanations.